# How to pass 1 column of a 2D matrix to a function in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D C-style array from which I have to pass just one column of it to a function. How do I do that?

Basically I need the C/C++ equivalent of the MATLAB command `A[:,j]` which would give me a column vector. Is it possible in C/C++?

Comment: The best way to do this is to pass a pointer to the first element in the column and jump forward through the array in increments of the length of the row. Are you familiar with pointers?

Comment: Transpose matrix and pass ith row

Comment: @POW the matrix is so huge I don't want to transpose it. It will hit my running time.

Comment: @P0W Matrix transpose is an $O(n^2)$ operation and unnecessary.

Comment: C++ has no true multidimensional arrays and no column slices.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz can you give me a small example?

Comment: You can consider using linear algebra package like: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html, or Rcpp http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html

Comment: @VivekVK You tagged your question `c++` but you used the term array, do you use c arrays in your code or c++ containers?

Comment: @Mayerz I use C arrays. Changed the tag. sorry about that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options,

1) Pass a pointer to your object (after moving it to the first element of the destination column)

> > > twoDArray[0][column]

Now you can calculate the next item for this column (by jumping through the elements)

2) Create a wrapper class that would do this for you.

```
custom2DArray->getCol(1);
.
.
.
class YourWrapper{
 private:
   auto array = new int[10][10];
 public:
   vector<int> getCol(int col);
}

YourWrapper:: vector<int> getCol(int col){
  //iterate your 2d array(like in option 1) and insert values 
  //in the vector and return
}
```

3) Use a 1d array instead. You can get this info easily. By jumping through rows and accessing the value for the desired column.(Mentioning just for the sake of mentioning, don't hold it against me)

Comment: Good options. will choose the first option as it is computationally cheap.

Answer (score 1):

```
int colsum(int *a, int rows, int col)
{
    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        sum += *(a + i*rows+col);
    }
    return sum;
}    


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int rows = 2;
    int cols = 2;    

    int i, j;    

    int *a;
    a = (int*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(int));

    // This just fills each element of the array with it's column number.
    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            *(a+i*rows + j) = j;    

        }
    }

    // Returns the sum of all elements in column 1 (second from left)
    int q = colsum(a, rows, 1);

    printf("%i\n", q);
    return 0;
}
```

It's not *exactly* passing the column, it's passing a pointer to the beginning of the array and then giving it instructions on how many rows the array has and which column to concern itself with.

Comment: Alternatively, you can define colsum to accept the pointer to the first element of the column (a+colnum) and ignore the col number pass. You'd call the function as colsum(a+colnum,rows);

Comment: Thank you. your answer can still be made faster by computing the required column number on the go I guess. ( like accessing a 1D array)

Answer (score 0):

considering your 2d array:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int> > *array = new std::vector<std::vector<int> >;
std::list myCol;

... //fill your array

//Here we iterate through each row with an iterator
for (auto it = array->begin(); it != array->end(); ++it)
    //Then we access the value of one col of this row
    myCol.push_back(it[col]);

//MyCol will be filled with the col values


        for col = 1, myCol=[8, 3, 1, 4]
        \/ 
it->[[2, 8, 4, 3],
\/   [6, 3, 9, 6],
     [9, 1, 3, 3],
     [2, 4, 2, 7]]
```

Comment: Isn't it row wise iteration?

Comment: I iterate through the rows but I always get the value at `col` index

Comment: This is an good solution to easily program but I have to do a O(n) operation. I cant afford it. my N here is so large.